# Generate Sorted Dictionary by Letters from an Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have an Array of Departments' Names

```
var departments: Array<String>!
```

I want to sort this array alphabetically in Dictionary e.g the dictionary should be like this

```
var MyDictionary = ["A": ["Affenpoo", "Affenpug", "Affenshire", "Affenwich", "Afghan Collie", "Afghan Hound"], "B": ["Bagle Hound", "Boxer"],
    "C": ["Cagle Cound", "Coxer"]]
```

the departments array is not static

how can i generate this dictionary in swift?

Thanks a lot

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: Iterate the array. Take the first letter of each entry. Retrieve the array from the dictionary for that letter. If it is nil create a new array with the word and add it to the dictionary. If it isn't nil, add the word to the array you retrieved.

Comment: What if there is no department starting with 'B'?

Comment: @vadian my goal is to have all the departments which start with the same letter associated with the same key in the dictionary

Comment: The suggestion of @Paulw11 is a suitable solution.

Comment: This sound a lot like homework to me, you shouldn't me asking these questions but trying out on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach would be to iterate the array and take the first letter of each entry. Retrieve the array from the dictionary for that letter. If it is nil create a new array. Add the word to the array you retrieved and then store the array in the dictionary.

```
let departments = ["Affenpoo", "Affenpug", "Affenshire", "Affenwich", "Afghan Collie","Cagle Cound", "Coxer"]
var outputDict=[String:[String]]()

for word in departments {
    let initialLetter=word.substringToIndex(word.startIndex.advancedBy(1)).uppercaseString
    var letterArray=outputDict[initialLetter] ?? [String]()
    letterArray.append(word)
    outputDict[initialLetter]=letterArray
}

print(outputDict)
```

> ["C": ["Cagle Cound", "Coxer"], "A": ["Affenpoo", "Affenpug", "Affenshire", "Affenwich", "Afghan Collie"]]

Comment: why C comes before A

Comment: It is a dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: solution by  Paulw11 is more efficient

I don't think this question is relevant to swift in particular, but anyways try this:

```
let a = ["All", "Cat", "red", "gat", "Star sun", "bet you", "Zeta Fog", "Tea", "Fox"]

let b = a.map{ $0.lowercaseString }

let c = b.sort()
let d = c.map{ $0[$0.startIndex.advancedBy(0)]}

var dictionary:[String:[String]] = [:]
let byInitial = d.map{ initial in

    let clustered = c.filter{$0.hasPrefix("\(initial)")}
    dictionary.updateValue(clustered, forKey:"\(initial)")
}
print("\(dictionary)")
```

Comment: This solution is O(n^2) due to calling `let clustered = c.filter{$0.hasPrefix("\(initial)")}` inside an outer iteration

Comment: Yes, it's O(n^2). OP didn't mention complexity constraints.

Comment: Still, avoiding O(n^2) when there is a straightforward O(n) solution is common sense